# Run Magento Store via .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, magento, magento-1.6

I have a fairly simple question which I thought would be easy to setup, but is proving difficult.

I have a Magento installation, and I want it to have 2 websites, with two languages on each. Then wehen I go on the tennis UK domain it loads the UK store. If I go on the French domain it loads the French store.

**This is how it is working now (INCORRECT):**

```
Tennis UK (website)
Tennis UK (store & store views)

Tennis FR (website)
Tennis FR (store & store views)

Volleyball UK (website)
Volleyball UK (store & store views)

Volleyball FR (website)
Volleyball FR (store & store views)
```

**This is how I'd prefer it to work (CORRECT):**

```
Tennis (website)
Tennis UK / Tennis FR (stores & store views)

Volleyball (website)
Volleyball UK / Volleyball FR (stores & store views)
```

In the htaccess I am running a script to run the correct website, but I thought that I should also be able to run a store code if needed, like this:

```
SetEnvIf Host www\.tennisukdomain\.co.uk MAGE_RUN_CODE=tennis_uk
SetEnvIf Host www\.tennisukdomain\.co.uk MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
SetEnvIf Host ^tennisukdomain\.co.uk MAGE_RUN_CODE=tennis_uk
SetEnvIf Host ^tennisukdomain\.co.uk MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
```

But this is not working for some reason. Does anybody know the correct way to get this working. By loading a store view instead of a website each time it will cut down on the amount of configuration I have to do in the admin.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Magento? "store" is the default run type, btw.

Comment: Quick debug: crack open *index.php* and `var_dump($_SERVER)` to check that your `mod_env` directives are working correctly.

Comment: I have dumped the server details but cannot see where mod_env is mentioned. Which key tells me this info?

Comment: `mod_env` is what you are using in your *.htaccess* file (`SetEnvIf`). If it is working you should see your environment variables in the dump of the `$_SERVER` superglobal.

Comment: Yes, all the server variables were output as expected.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10440/discussion-between-benmarks-and-adam-moss)

Comment: If the mod_env arguments are working correctly, then verify that your [*index.php* looks like this](http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.6/index.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by code. For example:

**index.php**

```
$host = explode(':', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
$dname = substr($host[0], -3,3);

switch ($dname) {
case '.uk':
   $store = 'tennis_uk';
   break;
case '.fr':
   $store = 'tennis_uk';
   break;
default:
   $store = '';
}

Mage::run($store);
```